# Error while executing bash command stored in string

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

Wrote a bash shell script that uses `rsync` to deploy files to live web server.

Right before executing, the script outputs the full command that the my shell script generates:

```
rsync --chmod="ug=rwx" -e="ssh" --filter="merge .deploy/filters" --dry-run --recursive -v --size-only "/var/www/vhosts/staging/mysite.com/httpdocs/" "me@mysite.com:/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/domains/mysite.com/httpdocs"
```

This is being run inside my shell script like so:

```
local command=`getDeploymentCommand "$deploy_direction" "$mode"`
echo $command
echo `$command`
```

... and produces the following error:

```
rsync: Invalid argument passed to --chmod ("ug=rwx")
```

The `chmod` syntax looks correct to me. What's really weird is that the actual command copy-pasted into the shell and executed works fine. Why is this, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the man page, the quotes aren't required, and are probably doing something unintended in the shell script versus pasted right into the command line. Try removing those quotes from your command.

The problem is that the shell allows variable interpolation inside double quotes. If you use single quotes, it doesn't allow interpolation, or you can escape-quote the quotes themselves to avoid interpolation.

Comment: The quotes are added automatically by my script for all parameter values. What about the `filter` parameter? That requires quotes to have `merge` in it, since it is followed by a space.

Comment: In the man page I'm looking at, the filter rule is surrounded by single quotes. This avoids interpolation of the string within the quotes, as opposed to double-quotes which allows interpolation.

Comment: In the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) I'm looking at, there is an example with double quotes. I see your point though, and here's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005192/how-to-execute-a-bash-command-stored-as-a-string-with-quotes-and-asterisk) on the subject. Write a comprehensive answer using this new information, and I will mark it as accepted, since you were essentially right

Comment: I simply modified this answer instead of adding a second answer.

Comment: You didn't add the `eval` method, which, I believe, would be the best answer, since it allows to use the string as-is.

Comment: If you don't want to accept the answer, you don't have to. I don't recommend using eval as it's far to susceptible to injection attacks. Ultimately, the answer is "You're using the quoting wrong, fix it." How you fix it is up to you and not part of my answer.

Comment: Anything that gets executed as part of an arbitrary string introduces injection vulnerability. Besides, my original question was also 'how can I make it work?'. I would have upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.